# How to adjust for non-uniform sampling (log-scale/polar) in Monte Carlo integration?

Tags: python-3.x, montecarlo, non-uniform-distribution

I am trying to perform Monte Carlo integration of a function, but sample non-uniformly. I need this method to work for both logarithmic scale and for integration in polar coordinates since I will then combine the two and use polar with log-scale sampling in radius.

I wrote a testing script that tries to

- integrate a 2D gaussian in polar coordinates (which should equal to pi)
- integrate y(x) = x in log-scale from 10**-2 to 10**7 (which should equal to ~0.5*10 ** 14)

For testing purposes, I complement the calculation with a uniform cartesian coordinate-based Monte Carlo that works. It is the non-uniformity of the sample that shifts my results.

```
import numpy as np


def function_to_integrate(x, y):
    return np.exp(-x**2 - y**2)


def polar_MC(polar):
    size = 100000
    integral = 0.
    integration_radius = 4.
    if polar:
        for _ in range(size):
            r = np.random.random()*integration_radius
            phi = np.random.random()*2.*np.pi
            x = r*np.cos(phi)
            y = r*np.sin(phi)
            jacobian_MC_polar = 1.
            integral += function_to_integrate(x, y) * jacobian_MC_polar
        integral = integral * np.pi * integration_radius**2 / size
    else:
        for _ in range(size):
            length = 2. * integration_radius
            x = np.random.random()*length - length/2.
            y = np.random.random()*length - length/2.
            integral += function_to_integrate(x, y)
        integral = integral * length**2 / size
    print('POLAR: True integral should be pi ', '; MC:', integral, polar)


def log_MC(log):
    size = 10000
    integral = 0.
    if log:
        for _ in range(size):
            x = np.random.uniform(-2, 7.)
            jacobian_MC_log = 1.
            integral += 10**x * jacobian_MC_log
    else:
        for _ in range(size):
            x = np.random.uniform(10**-2, 10**7)
            integral += x
    integral = integral*10**7 / size
    print('LOG: True integral should be 0.5*10**7*10**7 = 5*10**13; MC:', integral/10**13, '* 10**13', log)


polar_MC(polar=True)
polar_MC(polar=False)

log_MC(log=True)
log_MC(log=False)
```

I am unable to get the correct result from the polar and log-scale Monte Carlo, how should I set the jacobian_MC in order for this to work? Or am I doing something else wrong?

I have tried using the standard Jacobians (r for polar and r*np.log(10) for logarithmic) and that did not help.

With the Jacobians set to 1, I am getting

```
POLAR: True integral should be pi  ; MC: 11.041032315593327 True
POLAR: True integral should be pi  ; MC: 3.108344559871783 False
LOG: True integral should be 0.5*10**7*10**7 = 5*10**13; MC: 0.48366198481209793 * 10**13 True
LOG: True integral should be 0.5*10**7*10**7 = 5*10**13; MC: 5.003437412553992 * 10**13 False
```

Increasing sampling does not help, the results is close to being converged.

What probability distribution should I divide the sampled points with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You got both Jacobian and normalization parts wrong for polar integration

Here is the correct code, Python 3.10, Win x64

```
import numpy as np

rng = np.random.default_rng()

def integrand(x: np.float64, y: np.float64) -> np.float64:
    r = np.sqrt(x*x + y*y)
    jacobian = r
    return jacobian * np.exp(-r*r)

def sample_xy(R: np.float64):
    r = R * rng.random()
    phi = 2.0*np.pi*rng.random()

    return r*np.cos(phi), r*np.sin(phi)

N = 1000000
R = 100.0

s: np.float64 = 0.0

for k in range(0, N):
    x,y = sample_xy(R)

    s += integrand(x, y)

print(s/N * 2.0*np.pi*R)
```

it consistently prints values around 3.14:

```
3.155748795359562
3.14192687470938
3.161890183195259
```

UPDATE

This is not perimeter or area thing. This is how you make Probability Density Function (PDF).

So you have f(r)

f(r) = r e<sup>-r<sup>2</sup></sup>

and integrals

I = S<sub>0</sub><sup>2 pi</sup> d phi S<sub>0</sub><sup>R</sup> dr f(r)

You want to use Monte Carlo. It means sampling phi and sampling r. In order to sample something (anything!) you HAVE TO HAVE PDF (positive, properly normalized to 1 etc).

So lets start with integral over phi

I<sub>phi</sub> = S<sub>0</sub><sup>2 pi</sup> d phi.

I'll multiply and divide it by 2 pi.

I<sub>phi</sub> = 2 pi S<sub>0</sub><sup>2 pi</sup>  d phi/(2 pi).

which makes proper PDF under the integration sign

PDF(phi) = d phi/(2 pi)

and proper sampling

phi = 2 pi random()

But what's left is 2 pi upfront which you have to carry out to the front of the integral. This is how it works - you make normalized to 1 PDF under the integral, and whatever constant is there you account for it later, after whole sampling routine. It is not area nor perimeter, it is PDF construction and normalization

Same for radial integral

I<sub>R</sub> = S<sub>0</sub><sup>R</sup> dr = R S dr/R.

PDF(r) = dr/R, so you could sample r = R random(), but you have to carry R upfront to final calculation step.

Comment: Why did you normalize with 2*pi*R - the circumference of the integrated area? I thought it should be the area of the 2D integration - pi * R**2. Thank you very much for your reply! :)

Comment: Answered how PDFsa are constructed

Comment: Of course, thats is perfect! Thank you very much, I get it now :)

Comment: If you like the answer, please accept it. I would advice to split second probelm (log sampling) as separate question, this is good approach to have two questions for two problems. Then I could look at it over weekends